# SQL Server Service Broker queue event notification not raised

Tags: sql-server, messagebroker

**Environment**: SQL Server 2012 Express edition.

**Goal**: Setup SQL Server Service Broker with external activation, calling a command line app.

**What I have done so far:** created message types, contracts, initiator and receiver queues and corresponding services. I also did set up a notification queue, notification service and created event notification for the TargetQ. The event notification is configured so that when an event is raised, it should (I thnk) call the NotifySvc letting it know that there is work to be processed in TargetQ. Please feel free to correct me at any point – this is very new to me.

**What happens**: I have a trigger on a table that (upon insert) creates a message and calls the TargetSvc. The message arrives at the TargetQ happily. And this is where everything stops. I am not sure if the event notification for queue activation is never triggered or what, but the message never makes it to the NotifyQ. Therefore my EA app is never called.

I realize I am skipping a lot of detail around setup and configuration but, as the topic is new to me, I am hoping that you guys see something obvious. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: can you post the script you used to create this setup?

Comment: Dan - you are on the right track - I was able to go back and clean the script, passing variables where I could so it kept the names of all objects consistent.That worked, I can insert a record into the table and see the EA service being called (reading the log). Another issue I have is this: even though the EA service says that is is calling mu .net app, the app process never gets loaded. But all the appropriate queues are being drained.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the EA service is now successfully receiving the EventNotification message but the app process isn't getting loaded.  I think we'll need more information on those details to help further.

Comment: You understand correctly. Here is what the EA Service log looks like:
1/31/2015 9:30:12 PM VERBOSE Received event notification for [MyPC].[Test].[dbo].[TargetQueue].
1/31/2015 9:30:12 PM VERBOSE Application process C:\Projects\Activator\Activator\bin\Debug\Activator.exe was created: id = 9128.
1/31/2015 9:30:18 PM VERBOSE Application process id = 9128 has exited: exit code = 0, exit time = 1/31/2015 9:30:18 PM.

Comment: So EA did its job.  How do you know the console app didn't?

Comment: I wasn't seeing its process loaded in the process explorer. But I do now. and the app is being called correctly. The issues was the path to the exe. It seems strange, but I shortened it (by copying the exe to c:\temp) and it works now. Many thanks for your help.